# Not able to run jpf command :JPF exception, terminating: error reading class java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement

Tags: java, build, jpf

I am getting the below error when I try to run the jpf basset program. I was able to build jpf-core and jpf-actor successfully. Did anyone encounter this before? Am I missing out something? Appreciate your response/comments. Thanks.

```
 ~/b/p/j/jpf-core  bin/jpf gov.nasa.jpf.actor.Basset pi.Driver 3
[SEVERE] JPF exception, terminating: error reading class java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement
gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFileException: illegal constpool tag
    at gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFile.error(ClassFile.java:168)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFile.parseCp(ClassFile.java:1009)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFile.parse(ClassFile.java:827)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:803)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.loadClass(ClassInfo.java:1221)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.getResolvedClassInfo(ClassInfo.java:1207)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.loadInterfaceRec(ClassInfo.java:1994)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.loadInterfaceRec(ClassInfo.java:2000)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.getAllInterfaces(ClassInfo.java:2150)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM.registerStartupClass(JVM.java:531)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM.registerStartupClasses(JVM.java:510)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM.initialize(JVM.java:301)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.JPF.run(JPF.java:616)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.JPF.start(JPF.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.tool.Run.call(Run.java:76)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.tool.RunJPF.main(RunJPF.java:100)
---------------------- JPF error stack trace ---------------------
gov.nasa.jpf.JPFException: error reading class java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.loadClass(ClassInfo.java:1231)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.getResolvedClassInfo(ClassInfo.java:1207)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.loadInterfaceRec(ClassInfo.java:1994)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.loadInterfaceRec(ClassInfo.java:2000)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.getAllInterfaces(ClassInfo.java:2150)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM.registerStartupClass(JVM.java:531)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM.registerStartupClasses(JVM.java:510)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.JVM.initialize(JVM.java:301)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.JPF.run(JPF.java:616)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.JPF.start(JPF.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.tool.Run.call(Run.java:76)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.tool.RunJPF.main(RunJPF.java:100)
Caused by: gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFileException: illegal constpool tag
    at gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFile.error(ClassFile.java:168)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFile.parseCp(ClassFile.java:1009)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.classfile.ClassFile.parse(ClassFile.java:827)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:803)
    at gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.ClassInfo.loadClass(ClassInfo.java:1221)
    ... 15 more
 ~/b/p/j/jpf-core 
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's worth but mine turn out to be a problem with the Java version. JPF library was compiled with Java 8 while I was trying to use it in Java 7. Matching the java version worked out for me.